# .NET Core 2.2 docker core dumped troubleshooting

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I am running a netcore 2.2 webapi application tested and running with dotnet run.

When I run it on production with docker image it raises:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'EEFileLoadException*'
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I've overwriten the CMD execution of docker on interactive mode with:

```
docker run -it --name myws -p 5000:5000 myhub.docker.com/myws/myws:0.1.0-614 bash
```

Then I tried to see some verbose execution of my dll:

```
dotnet myws.dll --verbose
```

I also get the same output. I don't know what to do to troubleshoot in this case. Does dotnet runtime has a production command for tracing errors?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the versions of `NewtonSoft.Json` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` packages within your test project?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json Version="12.0.1" - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel not referenced explicitly

Comment: I've already seen this one.. maybe the root cause is the same. But in my case, the error still occurs even without a test project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a problem with this Newtonsoft.Json version (12.0.1), I changed it back to 11.0.2 and the error stopped.

Thanks @prd for the insight.